# Simple JOIN Syntax Not Working in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I am trying to add a join to an existing LINQ statement but my syntax is incorrect.
I looked [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/240648/Entity-FrameWork-Joins) for examples among other places yet, my construction is still not working. Visual Studio is throwing a hissy fit. Both datasets are in the context that I am trying to work with so not sure what I am doing wrong:

The red squiggly line under the "join" keyword produces the error "The type arguments cannot be inferred from the query" The "n" and "nc" aliases produce the error "Cannot resolve symbol"

[image]

**My Original, working statement**

```
 var query = from nc in context.NewClubs
                           where nc.ClubMasterCustomerId == clubMasterCustId
                           select nc;
               var results = query.Any();
```

**What I am trying to do (Illustrated in SQL)**

```
select nc.NewClubName,nc.Id from NewClub as nc
join NewClubBuilder ncb on ncb.NewClubId = nc.Id
where ncb.BuilderClubKeyNumber = 'K00841'
```

**My translation from SQL to LINQ (Not working)**

```
var query = from nc in context.NewClubs
            join n in context.NewClubBuilders on n.NewClubId equals nc.Id
            where nc.ClubMasterCustomerId == clubMasterCustId
            select nc;

            var results = query.Any();
```

Thanks

Comment: Can you define "hissy fit"? What's the exact error reported?

Comment: Hissy fit == I included a screenshot that shows the issues in red

Comment: what error is that near the join?

Comment: Could you create a entity relationship between NewClubs and NewClubBuilders so you don't have to specify the join in the query?

Comment: The red squiggly line under the "join" keyword produces the error "The type arguments cannot be inferred from the query"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Swith the join properties, so `nc.Id` is first

```
join n in context.NewClubBuilders on nc.Id  equals n.NewClubId
```

Comment: Got bitten by that one before - forgot order matters here. Thanks